# Nullify the localStorage and find it updated after component mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am nullifying the local storage on successful server response in my actions and then when I check the componentDidUpdate for the value of the localStorage I still see it persists. It is only after I refresh the page I see the correct updated null of localStorage. Does anyone have ideas on how to always get the updated localStorage.

here's the snippet of my action

```
 .then(parseRawResponseToJson, parseRejectedToJson)
      .then((jsonObj = {}) => {
        if ('error' in jsonObj) {
          dispatch(makeShowSnackbarAction(jsonObj.error));
          dispatch(makeLogoutFailureAction());
          return
        } else {
          localStorage.clear();
          dispatch(makeLogoutSuccessAction());
          dispatch(makeShowSnackbarAction('snack_logout_msg'));
        }
      });
```

I set isFetching to change value in the reducer

```
 case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
    st.isFetching = false
    break;
```

and when I call componentDidUpdate and log localStorage, I see the value still there:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { isFetching } = this.props;

    if (isFetching !== prevProps.isFetching) {
      console.log("something changed?")
      let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      this.setState({
        user,
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage.clear` is a synchronous method. After calling it, the storage will remain clear at every subsequent point in time unless it is filled again. Accordingly, your issue is likely due to one of the following:

1. Your `compondentDidUpdate` is firing before your server response. Ensure the order by adding `console.log(1);`, after `localStorage.clear();`, and `console.log(2);` after `let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));`.
2. A part of your application is writing to localStorage after it is being cleared, and before it is being read.

Unrelated, I would consider using `localStorage.removeItem` instead of clear, as it is more precise.

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks you , Your first point is exactly the issue. What would be a good way  to get componentDidUpdate to fire after the server response?

Comment: @ksenia I presume you can't change when the server responds, so you would have to change the componentDidUpdate. You are checking for a change in 'isFetching'. It is not clear to me when you are changing it. One thing is for sure: You are not rendering the component after 'isFetching' changes, after you cleared the storage. I don't see enough of the code for the exact solution.

More generally, if all your code is in the same component, then you could just setState in the server response and not use componentDidUpdate.